# Using lstat in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Hi every time i try to compile with GCC in Visual Studio Code i get this error,

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'lstat'; did you mean 'wstat'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I am not sure why im getting this or how to fix it

Comment: `lstat` is a variant of the `stat` with some special handling of symbolic links, and it's standard in POSIX. Windows isn't POSIX (even if it have a rather incomplete and unmaintained POSIX  compatibility layer) and it doesn't have symbolic links the way POSIX systems have it. Therefore the `lstat` function makes no sense in Windows. And I guess you're on Windows because of the mention of `wstat` which is a Windows-specific function (it's not POSIX).

Comment: so is there anyway to get the program to compile properly using lstat or does the c program have to be written in unix. For context its supposed to be used in linux but Im writing it with VSC on a windows machine

Comment: Use conditional compilation? Use [`_stat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=vs-2019) when on Windows, and `lstat` otherwise.

Comment: [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-170

For Windows _stat() the documentation says:

**st_ino**
The inode, and therefore st_ino, has no meaning in the FAT, HPFS, or NTFS file systems.

**st_nlinks**
st_nlink Always 1 on non-NTFS file systems.

Unfortunately for my Windows 10 NTFS system using VS2019 it is also always 1 even though GetFileInformationByHandle() shows 2 for this.

The solution is to use GetFileInformationByHandle().